# Apache2: redirect using userdir http://website/~username -> http://{username}.other.website.com, URL gets cut off

Tags: apache, debian, apache2, directive

I'm trying to use Apache2 userdir to redirect user home directories to external URLs, where the username is at the beginning of the URL (`http://www.{USERNAME}.example.com/`). The result is that everything after the username is cut off:

```
UserDir http://www.*.other.website.com/
```

This will redirect to `http://www.{USERNAME}` and the rest will get cut off. Basically you can't use it unless it's in the path section of the URL. Is it possible to achieve this without the use of redirect module?

I tried all possible configurations.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```html
redirect permanent "/foo/"   "http://www.example.com/"
```

Comment: This doesn't help, I need `userdir` to redirect all usernames to different URL.